# Edit a JSON object

Tags: node.js

I retrieved a JSON object from a local database, I want to edit a value (`invItems`) and add a new value to it (`filed[filed.invItems]`), then upload it back to the database, but it does not seem to work (the JSON does not seem to change)

```js
async function invPut(itemID, message) {
  var filed = await frenzyDB.getKey(id + "_invcache");
  console.log("Before: " + filed)
  newInvItems = filed.invItems + 1;
  filed.invItems = newInvItems;
  filed[filed.invItems] = itemID;
  console.log("After: " + filed);
  await frenzyDB.addKey(id + "_invcache", filed)
}
```

Console Output:

```
Before: {"invItems":0}
After: {"invItems":0}
```

It shows no errors, but the JSON doesnt change. Am I doing something wrong? If so, what can I do to fix it?
Thanks for all your help!

Notes:
frenzyDB is just a javascript file that deals with a standard REPL.it Database

Code of frenzyDB:

```js
const Database = require("@replit/database")
const db = new Database()

async function addKey(key, value) {
  await db.set(key, value).then(() => {return;});
}

async function getKey(key) {
  return await db.get(key).then(value => {return value;});
}

function listAllKeys() {
  db.list().then(keys => {return keys;});
}

async function hasKey(key) {
  var keys = await listAllKeys();
  if (keys.includes(key)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

async function removeKey(key) {
  await db.delete(key).then(() => {return;});
}

module.exports = {
  addKey,
  getKey,
  listAllKeys,
  hasKey,
  removeKey
};
```

**Edit**: Latest code:

```js
async function invPut(itemID, message) {
  await init(message.author.id);
  var filed = await frenzyDB.getKey(message.author.id + "_invcache");
  console.log(filed)
  const result = {};
  result.invItems = (filed['invItems'] + 1) || 1;
  result.hasOwnProperty(filed.invItems) ? result[filed.invItems + 1] = itemID : result[filed.invItems] = itemID;
  console.log(result);
  frenzyDB.addKey(message.author.id + "_invcache", result)
  message.reply("A **"+ itemIDs[itemID].name + "** was placed in your inventory");
  return true;
}
```

**EDIT 2:** Latest Console Output:

```
{ '4': 3, invItems: 5 }
{ '5': 3, invItems: 6 }
```

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
// Demo Data
const itemID = 10;
var filed = { "invItems" : 0 };

// Real function

console.log("Before: " + JSON.stringify(filed));
const result = {};
result.invItems = (filed['invItems'] + 1) || 1;
result.hasOwnProperty(filed.invItems) ? result[filed.invItems + 1] = itemID : result[filed.invItems] = itemID;
console.log("After: " + JSON.stringify(result));
```

The result I get is

```
Before: {"invItems":0}
After: {"0":10,"invItems":1}
```

You would then of course use `result` to store the data away in the DB.

```js
async function invPut(itemID, message) {
  // Typo?
  var filed = await frenzyDB.getKey(itemID + "_invcache");
  console.log("Before: " + filed)
  const result = {};
  result.invItems = (filed['invItems'] + 1) || 1;
  result.hasOwnProperty(filed.invItems) ? result[filed.invItems + 1] = itemID : result[filed.invItems] = itemID;
  console.log("After: " + result);
  // Typo?
  await frenzyDB.addKey(itemID + "_invcache", result)
}
```

---

Answer Edit:

```js
const result = { ...filed };

result.invItems = (filed['invItems'] + 1) || 1;

result.hasOwnProperty(filed.invItems) ? result[filed.invItems + 1] = itemID : result[filed.invItems] = itemID;

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: @corrupt_disk1 No problem, welcome to StackOverflow and sorry you had downvotes on your question (its very rude) but next time be sure to include supporting code so its clear and merry christmas!

Comment: Hey again, 
A problem would be that if I needed to add something again, it would overwrite the first value. 
For example, if I had ``{ '1': 3, invItems: 2 }`` and I ran the command again, rather than 
``{ '1': 3, '2': 3, invItems: 3 }`` i get ``{ '2': 3, invItems: 3 }``.
Is there a way to combat this? Thanks

Comment: Sorry I did not see your recent comment, thanks for your support and Merry Christmas too!
PS: I dont mind the downvotes, it teaches me to be clearer next time!

Comment: @corrupt_disk1 Replace `result[filed.invItems] = itemID;` with `result.hasOwnProperty(filed.invItems) ? result[filed.invItems + 1] = itemID : result[filed.invItems] = itemID;` that should do the trick.

Comment: hey again, it did not seem to work. I have updated my question with my latest code, would you mind telling me what I am doing wrong? Sorry I am a beginner to JavaScript

Thanks once again!

Comment: Can you post the content of ```console.log(result);``` so I can see whats happening, thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer with an edit, see if that does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help you

```
const json = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/data/data.json`, "utf-8");
const inputData = JSON.parse(json);

inputData.push({input: 'front'})  // creates new element for data.json  
   -------------------------------------------
array.push({front: 'front', back: 'back'});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am not sure this will work for me since all my JSON data is in the database I mentioned above.
If i try it with the database data i get ``(node:262) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: filed.push is not a function``

Comment: Thanks again for your edits, I appreciate the time you took to tell me the answer
However, this won't work for me due to the error that it gives me (look at my first comment)
Is there a way of achieveing this without using the ``.push()`` method?